# How to pass the arguments written in a .txt to a java program by the ubuntu terminal?

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal

I'm trying to make a java program run numerous times by passing the commands with the different arguments to the Ubuntu terminal, through a `.txt`. But I have no idea how to do it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find Karol's response to be great, however another suggestion to show there are many ways to do this on Unix :)

Suppose your class is called JavaClass and arguments stored on .txt

```
xargs -a .txt java JavaClass
```

Has same effect than

```
java JavaClass $(cat .txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cat` to print the `a.txt` before calling `java`:

```
java $(cat a.txt)
```

It might be easier to convert `a.txt` into a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
jargs="-version"
java $jargs
```